# How can we play yu-gi-oh online after dueling network's shutdown?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, online

Dueling network [shut down after a cease and desist letter](https://ygorganization.com/cd-order-filed-against-dueling-network/). Is there any way to play yu-gi-oh casually online now?

I used to like the ability to just make any deck and play casually, I am trying to see if anything took its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of DarkCygnus' answer, the "spiritual successor" to Dueling Network is [Dueling Book](https://duelingbook.com). It is stylized in the way Dueling Network used to be, has both a competitive ladder and casual matchmaking, and is a "manual" simulator (you have to resolve the effects of cards yourself, place them in the zones they should be in, etc.) The other simulators in DarkCygnus' solution are "automatic" simulators, that give you prompts for things like activation windows for cards and proper zones monsters can be summoned into.

If you are looking for something similar to Dueling Network, Dueling Book would be my recommendation.

Comment: +1 Whoa, yes. This one has more the look-and-feel of the old Dueling Network for sure! (just by looking at the home page)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to play yu-gi-oh casually online now?

I've heard and seen that [Dueling Nexus](https://duelingnexus.com/login) is a good place to play online (seems it's even automated), after Dueling Network shut down years ago.

Another suggestion many people use and mention is [YGO Pro](https://ygopro.org/), which seems to have a Chrome version (I have used the mobile ones, though).